# Inject to journey using salesforce data for new CaseComment not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We are trying to inject a contact into a journey via salesforce data ENTRY EVENT for every new creation of CaseComment object.
But have 0 contacts evaluated every time.

**Here are the settings:**

WHO: CreatedBy.Contact ID (Contact)

OBJECT: CaseComment

ACTION: Created

ENTRY DATA:
CaseComment:Id; CaseComment:CreatedBy:Contact:HasOptedOutOfEmail; CaseComment:CreatedBy:Contact:Email; CaseComment:CreatedBy:Contact:Id;

Comment: Please elaborate on your use case as in Salesforce, CaseComment records can be created by users with the "Create" permission on the CaseComment object, not the Contact related to the Case.
So entry data would be something like below.

Who
CreatedBy ID (User)

CaseComment:Id; CaseComment:CreatedBy:User:Email; CaseComment:CreatedBy:User:Id;
I am not sure how you are getting ContactID

and how your data model in CRM relating CaseComment, User and Contact

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations,
`caseComment` cannot inject a contact.
So, we took the Case object and added a custom field `Send_Push_Notification__c` with the default `False` and auto-update to `True` when a new `caseComment` is created.

So new `caseComment` and `Send_Push_Notification__c = True` will inject contact into the journey.

Then in the journey, we update `Send_Push_Notification__c` to `False` again.

[image]

Works very well.